# Email fail to send when adding attachment (using gmail smtp server in asp.net c# page)

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, gmail

email fail to send when adding attachment, else it's successful

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string temp = Session["captcha"].ToString();
    if (temp == txtCaptcha.Text)
    {
        var mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add(@"my mail");
        mail.From = new MailAddress("another email", "it's name",
            System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        mail.Subject = "my subject";
        mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        mail.Body = this.txtDescription.Text.Replace("\n", "<br>");
        mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High;
        var client = new SmtpClient();
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mail", "password");
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        try
        {
            if (this.fiUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                this.fiUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("MyAttach/" + fiUpload1.FileName));
                mail.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(Server.MapPath("MyAttach/" + fiUpload1.FileName)));
            }
            client.Send(mail);
            Page.RegisterStartupScript("UserMsg", "<script>alert('Successfully Send...');</script>");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Exception ex2 = ex;
            string errorMessage = string.Empty;
            while (ex2 != null)
            {
                errorMessage += ex2.ToString();
                ex2 = ex2.InnerException;
            }
            Page.RegisterStartupScript("UserMsg", "<script>alert('Sending Failed...');</script>");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Invalid Captcha, try again");
        FillCapctha();
    }
}
```

so what am i doing wrong, also should i save the files to my server first or could i just attach it from the client's ?

thanks and have a wonderful day

Comment: what is the error? can you make it more clear?